# Why Next build is not skipping validity type check even it is clearly mentioned to do so in next.config.js file by setting ignoreBuildError : true?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript, yarn-v2

I tried re-installing the typescript multiple time, updated the typescript version, node version, react types version but still it checks for valid types and the build breaks

versions-
node -16.20.2,
typescript - 4.5.2,
next js - 13.4.19,
react types - 17.0.13

next.config.js -

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
const runtimeCaching = require("next-pwa/cache");
const { i18n } = require("./next-i18next.config");

module.exports = withPWA({
i18n,
pwa: {
disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
dest: "public",
runtimeCaching,
},
async redirects() {
return [
  {
    source: "/",
    destination: "/home ",
    permanent: false,
  },
  ];
 },
  images: {
  domains: [
  "maps.googleapis.com",
  "googleusercontent.com",
  "graph.facebook.com",
  "res.cloudinary.com",
  "s3.amazonaws.com",
  "127.0.0.1",
    ],
   },
  typescript: {
  ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
 });
```

tsconfig.json -

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": ".",
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"noEmit": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"alwaysStrict": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noUnusedParameters": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"jsx": "preserve",
"paths": {
  "@assets/": ["src/assets/"],
  "@components/": ["src/components/"],
  "@contexts/": ["src/contexts/"],
  "@data/": ["src/data/"],
  "@settings/": ["src/settings/"],
  "@ts-types/": ["src/ts-types/"],
  "@utils/": ["src/utils/"]
}


},

    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "src/*/.ts", "src/*/.tsx", "src/*/.js", "src/data/user",                "src/pages/jee_mains_paper/student_login_form.tsx"],
   "exclude": ["node_modules"]
    }
```

error on build-

```
yarn build
yarn run v1.22.5
$ next build
info  - Loaded env from /var/www/complete-project/admin     /.env.local
 info  - Loaded env from /var/www/complete-project  /admin/.env
 info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default    https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
 Failed to compile.

./src/components/all-shop-visitors/all-shop-visitor-list.tsx:4:1
 Type error: 'ROUTES' is declared but its value is never read.

 2 | import { Table } from "@components/ui/table";
  3 | import ActionButtons from "@components/common/action-  buttons";
> 4 | import { ROUTES } from "@utils/routes";
     | ^
   5 | import { CategoryPaginator } from "@ts-types/generated";
   6 | import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
    7 | import { useIsRTL } from "@utils/locals";
   error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message from build?

Comment: when i run yarn build it starts checking for validity types and then build break due to and minor type error or warning in code......it is not a runtime error

Comment: Yup but at least provides some kind of logs so everyone can know the context better